# Problem with leaves in import of tree fbx

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, import

I'm using Blender for a masters research project and am new enough to it. It's a great tool! I've imported an fbx model of a tree (using Cycles Render) but the leaves aren't rendering properly - they appear as rectangles rather than leaf shapes. The leaf textures all seem to be there. There's some problem with the alpha channel possibly, but I can't figure it out. Importing the fbx into unreal works fine (it renders correctly).

Any help figuring this out would be greatly appreciated! I've tried everything I know to fix it without success. The fbx can be downloaded from here https://developer.nvidia.com/orca/speedtree. I've tried a couple of trees. It's mainly the Red Maple Young high poly one I've been trying to get working.

Here's a screenshot of my rendered image

[image: Rendered image]

Maria

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/